# How to extract profile_pic of a user when they are signing in from Google

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth, django-settings, scopes

I'm making a django website, I have 2 login methods. One is the default email password login and another is by logging in from Google.

What I want is when the user logs in from google django should automatically fetch the profile_pic of that user and save it in my user model.

Here's my `models.py` for `accounts` app

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager, Group


# Custom User Manager
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name=None, **extra_fields):
        if (not email):
            raise ValueError("Email Must Be Provided")
        if (not password):
            raise ValueError("Password is not Provided")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields)

    def create_user_with_groups(self, email, password, first_name, last_name=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)

        user = self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name)
        group = Group.objects.get(name='Content Writer')

        user.groups.add(group)
        print(user.groups)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields)


# Custom user Model
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profile_pics/users',
                                    default='default_profile_pic.svg')

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

Is there any way of achieving this? If there is, then it would be preferred to have a solution using `SCOPES`

Here is my `settings.py` file for `SCOPES`

```
...
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'MyApp.adapter.MySocialAccountAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
...
```

**EDIT:** I found the 'picture' field in the extra data of my social account profile in admin panel. How do I make use of that value in 'picture' field in the 'profile_pic' field of my User model. What function should I write to overwrite the default functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by getting user extra_data and after getting profile picture link:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

extra_data = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user).extra_data
print(extra_data['picture'])
```

In this way you get extra_data as a dictionary so you can simply extract profile picture

Answer (score 1):

When you are using allauth in django . You get 3 more models.
Go to your admin panel , under Social Accounts you will find all these models.

1. Social Account
2. Social Application Token
3. Social Application

The first one ( Social Account ) object has a field of extra  data . Go to any of the social account object and see the field extra data . You will have a text form dictionary . This will have the key profile_image ( or some other field name probably ) which will have the profile image url of the google logged in user .

Then just make a simple Django ORM .
profile_image = dict(SocialAccount.objects.get(id = some_id).extra_data)["profile_image"]
you will have the url .

Comment: I don't get this part 
"Then just make a simple Django ORM . profile_image = dict(SocialAccount.objects.get(id = some_id).extra_data)["profile_image"] you will have the url ."

Comment: In that part , I said , create a simple query to fetch the profile_image from the extra field in the Social Account model.  You could either use signal to do this or you can do it in the view. But using django signal is the best way to achieve this . If you want the code , let me know .

Comment: Ya i would love to have the code. As I don't know pretty much anything about signals! I will check out some tutorial on signals after this to understand the code!

Comment: Ok , I am writing the code. Could you just send me a pic or data in your any social account object or the structure of the extra field in the social account. I haven't seen it in time . I'll write the code. And also hide your information which is sensitive.

Comment: Updated the post with the picture of social account!

Answer (score 0):

I have used DJ REST Auth Package for social sign-in and signup
https://pypi.org/project/dj-rest-auth/

```
# in you setting file
# >>>  Social Authentication Settings

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_ENABLED = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQURIED=True
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool("ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
SOCIALACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool("SOCIALACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
    }
 
#I have written a method to get image from a url 
import requests
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
def save_image_from_url(model, url, name):
    r = requests.get(url)
    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    img_temp.write(r.content)
    img_temp.flush()
    model.name = name
    model.profile_picture.save("{}.jpg".format(model.username), File(img_temp), save=True)

# Viewset for google login
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    callback_url = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"

    def get_response(self):
        serializer_class = self.get_response_serializer()
        user = self.user
        user_extra_data = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first().extra_data
        name = user_extra_data["name"]
        profile_image_url = user_extra_data["picture"]
        if not user.profile_picture:
            save_image_from_url(user, profile_image_url, name)
        user_detail = UserSerializer(user, many=False, context={"request": self.request})
        serializer = serializer_class(instance=self.token, context={'request': self.request})
        resp = serializer.data
        resp["token"] = resp["key"]
        resp.pop("key")
        resp["user"] = user_detail.data
        response = Response(resp, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return response
```

Comment: Where have you written this code as in what file? (views.py, models.py, or made some new file of your own)?

Comment: Are you asking about this method 'save_image_from_url' ? @KushagraGupta

Comment: yes talking about 'save_image_from_url'

Comment: I have written it in views files. you can write it any where you want just import that method and call it with the parameters @KushagraGupta